# How to get text from radio option value

Tags: 8, webforms

How do I get the option text from the submitted value of the radio field in Drupal 8 webform submission? I have written a rule action condition on webform submission where I am storing data in a middle table.

Based on screen I am looking for Option Text from webform field. 
Current version: Drupal 8.6.15 & webform 8.x-5.2

[image]
[image]

Comment: ... Drupal 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Drupal 8 (since you didn't give a version), there are two parts to this.

Imagine this element in the form:

```
$form['some_field'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [
    'option1' => $this->t('Option 1'),
    'option2' => $this->t('Option 2'),
  ],
];
```

The submitted value can be retrieved from $form_state in your submit handler:

```
$radio_value = $form_state->getValue('some_field');
```

You can then use the value to get the text of the radio, from the $form element:

```
$radio_text = $form['some_field']['#options'][$radio_value];
```